# Tex adding information to txt

Tags: input, include, write

Is there any possibility to add Information to a .txt or other type of document?

For example I have the following .tex

```
\begin{filecontents*}{Info.tex}
    @ P  & 1 &  60 &  2 & 77 \\
    @ B  & 2 &  90 &  4 & 64 \\
    @ O  & 3 & 100 & 10 &  6 \\
\end{filecontents*}
```

And the new .tex add the following line

```
\begin{filecontents*}{Info.tex}
    @ P  & 1 &  60 &  2 & 77 \\
    @ B  & 2 &  90 &  4 & 64 \\
    @ O  & 3 & 100 & 10 &  6 \\
    @ Z  & 4 &   0 &  7 &  6 \\
\end{filecontents*}
```

Comment: I try it with \newwrite and \newwrite, but its not work how I imagined

Comment: It is a bit unclear to me what you want to achieve. Where does the information come from that you want to write to the external file?

Comment: Do you mean you want to append lines to an existing file?

Comment: Yes, how can I append lines to an existing file?